# Pycron does not run only when the console is started

Tags: python, windows, authorization

I want to run batch files with Pycron under windows 10, but Pycron will only start running at the specified time if the pycron console is open.
I think there is an authorization issue while running the pycron service but i couldn't resolve it.
What could be the reason for this has someone ever encountered such a problem?

Thank you for your help.